# Associate the color of a TextColor of a Label in a DataTemplate to a Resource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have elements of a `List` inside a `StackLayout` in `Binding`. Inside the `DataTemplate` I have a `Label` with Gray `TextColor`. At the press of a button I would like the color of the `TextColor` to become the color of a `resource` I have within the application. How could I do?

**c#**

```
public class Giorni
{
   public string Color {get;set;}
}

List<Giorni> listgiorni = new List<Giorni>
{
   new Giorni{},
}


BindableLayout,SetItemsSource(StackLayout, listgiorni);
```

**XAML:**

```
   <Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="AppPrimaryColor">#1976D2</Color>
   </ApplicationResource>
```

.....

```
   <StackLayout>
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Label TextColor="Gray" Text="Hello"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to bind `Color` from `Giorni` to Label's `TextColor`.
If that is the case, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in Giorni, and then add binding in XAML `<Label TextColor="{Binding Color}" Text="Hello"/>`

Here's the complete sample app with button changing the color of the label:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="MyStackLayout">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label TextColor="{Binding Color}" Text="Hello"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate> 
        </StackLayout>
        <Button Clicked="OnButtonClicked" Text="Change Color!"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
    public class Giorni:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _color;
        public string Color
        {
            get { return _color; }
            set { _color = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        List<Giorni> listgiorni = new List<Giorni>
            {
                new Giorni{},
            };
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listgiorni[0].Color = "Gray";
            BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(MyStackLayout, listgiorni);    
        }
        void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            listgiorni[0].Color = "Red";
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**: After clarification of `resource`, here's the edited `OnButtonClicked`.
Since your resource is `Color`, you need to change it to `string` appropriately, because Giorni's Color is `string`.

```
        void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Color color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["AppPrimaryColor"];
            int red = (int)(color.R * 255);
            int green = (int)(color.G * 255);
            int blue = (int)(color.B * 255);
            listgiorni[0].Color = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", red, green, blue );
        }
```

A better solution would be to change your Giorni's Color property from `string` to `Color` type.
Then in `OnButtonClicked` you can just put:

```
        void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            listgiorni[0].Color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["AppPrimaryColor"];
        }
```

Comment: In your example, you changed the text from Gray to red. Instead, I would like it initially to be gray, and with the button it would then have the color of a shared Color resource for the whole project

Comment: What is your `shared Color resource`, can you share add that in your question?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If this works for you, please accept the answer. If not, please describe what is the problem.